# How to open pickList of ComboboxItem/SelectItem manually/programatically using SmartGWT?

Tags: java, combobox, smartgwt

I'm using SmartGWT 2.5 with Java & Mozilla FF 3.6.x.
I want to open **pickList** of **ComboboxItem** or **SelectItem** manually that means programatically. Is it possible? It's OK if I need to use JavaScript to achieve this. Any hint or solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the answer. Posting it here might be useful to others. I've used

```
comboxItem.showPicker();
```

to achieve manual opening of picklist of `ComboboxItem`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work with SelectItem, though (at least in SmartGWT 2.4).

Comment: @jewbix.cube, can you try `comboboxItem.getPicker().isVisible()`?

Comment: @RAS tried that but `getPicker()` seems to always return `null`, even though `showPicker()` works.

Comment: @jewbix.cube, well in that case, I don't think there is any such method that can give us the state of the comboboxitem.

Answer (score 1):

In SmartGWT 2.4 (I didn't check newer versions), the `showPicker()` method of SelectItem does only show an empty div, not the pick list of the select item. (It does work for the ComboBoxItem, as mentioned by RAS' answer).

Some digging into the underlying SmartClient code showed that on the JavaScript side, there is a `showPickList()` method which is called when the icon is clicked (or on some other events), but this is not exposed by the Java class.

So I used a piece of JSNI (modified from the source code of `SelectItem.showPicker`) to call this method:

```
public static native void showPickList(SelectItem item) /*-{
   var jsItem = item.@com.smartgwt.client.core.DataClass::getJsObj()();
   if(jsItem.showPickList) {
      jsItem.showPickList();
   }
}-*/
```

Calling `showPickList(item)` for any such pick list now opens the picker.